# Wordpress MySQL Query Results - How to Highlight Strings Found in Displayed Table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, highlight

I have created a functioning WordPress page with two search boxes (and a pair of and/or buttons between them) that queries an sql database and returns a two-column table with rows that contain one (or both, as the case may be) of the searched-for strings ($search and $search2) and then paginates when results exceed 100 rows. I have tried three different methods of highlighting these strings in the table but can't get it to work. So I'd much appreciate some help. The relevant portion of the php code (for which I am using the WordPress Insert PHP plug-in) is:

```
[insert_php]

* * * * 

if ($andor == "and"){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DATE(start_date), EVENT FROM {$table} WHERE EVENT REGEXP '$search'  >0 AND EVENT REGEXP '$search2' >0 LIMIT {$limits}");
}
else{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DATE(start_date), EVENT FROM {$table} WHERE EVENT REGEXP '$search'  >0 OR EVENT REGEXP '$search2' >0 LIMIT {$limits}");
}
 * * * *
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td>$cell</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}

[/insert_php]
```

First, I added a function to the functions.php file and tried calling it and couldn't make it work

```
function highlight_word( $content, $word) {
    $replace = '<span style="background-color: #FF0;">' . $word . '</span>'; 
    $content = str_replace( $word, $replace, $content ); 
    return $content; 
};
```

Then I tried a string replacement in a separate while loop. Finally I tried changing the existing while loop as follows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td>" . str_replace($search, '<span style="background-color: #FF0;">' . $search . '</span>', $cell) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

It would be helpful if I could limit the highlighting to the second column("EVENTS") only, but this is much less important than simply getting it to work.  And, yes, I will upgrade code to mysqli and escape query strings before finalizing. As always, thanks to all in this great community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why won't you use some highlight js library?

[mark.js](https://markjs.io/) supports highlighting in tables out of the box

```
$("table tr td:nth-child(1)").mark('keyword');
```

[Check this example](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/1at87fnu/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, mark.js looks good.  But I have to figure out how to add it to my WordPress site, something I do not know how to do. I will comment again after looking into this.

Comment: So far have added mark.js but can't yet get it to run properly on a page . . . still trying.

Comment: 90% of the way there. Highlighting is working with keywords that I specify in the code. I need to figure out how to make my two php search variables ("$search" and "$search2") available to JQuery as the keywords to be highlighted by mark.js.

Comment: Got it working with some great help on the jquery.com forum. (Output the variables in a defined <div> in html and them picked them up with jQuery).